# I have been betrayed and isolated by my advisor and I am mentally drained. What should I do now?

Tags: phd, research-process, ethics

I'm in the middle of a complicated situation, and I'm wondering whether this is commonplace in academia.

Long story short: I'm an international student, and I recently completed my master's degree in CS. I had been working with one adviser (Prof A), I completed my course work in December, but since Prof A couldn't find worthy candidates to fill my place, Prof A told me that if I assist her with her research projects for one more semester, she will help me find a job. Fast forward two months, she told me in a meeting that she tried to help but she can't and that I should look for a job on my own. I recently asked if I could pursue a PhD in her lab. She said no, as she has no funding. I've successfully applied to a different lab (Prof B), only to find out that all professors are provided funding for first-year graduate students. **Why would she lie about this? Is this normal?**

The situation has since developed that I've been able to play my acceptance to Prof B's lab off of Prof A, and she was very happy to take me on now that I'm working on B's research; she clearly hopes to get research funding out of this new-found collaboration. This seems incredibly callous to me; she clearly has no interest in my situation, and simply wants more grant money. **Is this normal behavior for academics?** I was on the edge of being deported, and she clearly could not care less about my personal situation, only for her research money. **Are all academics this callous?**

Comment: Calm. Even if other people are behaving dishonestly and/or childishly, you should restrain yourself from responding in that fashion. Don't "engage" on those terms. Professors should take care for the scholastic welfare of students, not exploit them, certainly, and if they fail, then there is no dishonor in your taking your own welfare into your own hands. Don't apologize to someone who has proven their disinterest in your welfare.

Comment: Why not search other universities and institutions. US has many great universities and CS departments.

Comment: _Should i tell my advisor sorry?_ — **NO!** You have nothing to aoplogize for.

Comment: By the way, the existence of departmental funding for first-year graduate students does not indicate that your advisor was lying about funding, since you need a lot more than one year of funding to complete a Ph.D.  It would be irresponsible for her to take on another student without a reliable plan for securing funding for the rest of their studies.

Comment: Still, don't allow yourself to be drawn into morally or ethically dubious situations. Don't allow yourself to participate in a professional "drama", even when it seems it's already happening. The "deportation" issue is irrelevant to scholarly merit, by the way, so don't confuse your visa issues with research issues or ethical issues... First try to imagine what you'd decide if visa issues didn't exist, as a baseline. Then see how far you must compromise yourself because of visa issues, and determine whether you are willing. No, people are not all jerks, but many are.

Comment: Your update is best asked as a second question. But no, advisors are not normally like this.  It sounds like you need a new advisor, if not a new department.

Comment: @JeffE i have posted it as another question. Here it is -http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17399/i-need-advice-on-how-i-should-handle-a-potential-awakward-situation-with-my-advi

Comment: @eykanal That edit completely changed the question. It makes more sense to delete (or revert) this question and post a new one rather than do this.

Comment: @trutheality - I disagree that it completely changed the question. It definitely edited it, but I just tried to summarize what was a lot of story into his basic questions. If others disagree they can definitely flag for deletion.

Comment: @eykanal the initial question was basically "this is my situation, what should I do now." What it is now, is "this was my situation, this is the action I took, this is the result, now please explain the psychology behind my advisor's actions."

Comment: @trutheality - Perhaps you missed the [edit](http://academia.stackexchange.com/revisions/17340/2), that added a bunch of questions about whether this is common. There were also a few "what should I do now" questions which are too localized for this forum, and which I removed in the edit.

Comment: @eykanal I know, I saw the history. I think that instead of letting the edit go through as a moderator you should have educated Boneck35 on proper SE etiquette, e.g. not completely changing a question by editing it a day after it has been asked. When new information turns up and created new related questions, it's ok to post new questions and link to old ones for context. It's up to you and the other mods how to run things here, but it just looked like you encouraged that change, which is unusual to me.

Comment: @trutheality - [We actually had this discussion before](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/258/when-is-an-edit-not-an-edit-any-more), and quite frankly, I forgot about that. It seems that the proper thing to do would have been to delete it. I should have remembered that discussion, my fault.

Comment: trutheality's answer is excellent. If prof A doesn't have funding beyond first year, she _should_ have clearly stated so. If that is the case, I wouldn't necessarily call her later actions callous at all. Maybe she just genuinely wants to collaborate with a good student. I would withhold judgement until you can make the distinction between poor communication and manipulative action.

Comment: @Moriarty The advisor refuses PhD and when other senior professor offers to work with me on a PhD ,she suddenly wants to become co -adviser so that she could go to that client and pitch her own project to them. When that didn't work out ,and i asked her for PhD again, she said she doesn't has plans to take any new PhD students for next 2-3 years .There were 2 other people in my thesis committee defense.Both offered me a Phd but i could work with only one of them as the other Prof's projects need security clearance. Why would they offer me a PhD if i was just not good enough?

Comment: @Moriarty "Maybe she just genuinely wants to collaborate with a good student."Can you please clarify what you meant by this?

Comment: @Boncek35 perhaps there was merely a miscommunication about the whole funding issue, rather than Prof A acting maliciously. It's possible that she still wants to work with you in good faith (but just cannot support you financially). Basically, I'm saying that her intent _may not_ be malicious.

Answer (score 26):

So essentially, what you need is someone to take you on as a PhD. It looks like your current advisor just isn't interested in having you be her PhD student. This other professor is interested in having you as a PhD student, but you aren't interested in his research.

It sounds like neither of these is an option for doing a PhD. This means that you need to find someone else to be your advisor. Think about who else is in your department.

Other than that, your only choices are probably to find a job or leave the country.

(I'm not mentioning trying to apply to another university because I think admission season is almost over for most, but there might be some places still accepting applications.)

---

Post-edit things:

> Why would she lie about this? Is this normal?

First of all, you don't know if she lied. You have no idea under what constraints she operates. Yes, you've been told first-years get funding, but a PhD is more than a year, so what is she supposed to do with you after that, if she really doesn't have funding? That would have been worse, spending a year working for her and then being deported, don't you think?

Secondly, if she did lie, she might have done it because she doesn't tell you what's really preventing her from taking you on. What if you're not as good a researcher as you think you are and she doesn't want you working on her project? What if she got funding from a grant that requires the participants to be citizens, and she's trying to get another student, who actually qualified for it, to join her? There are lots of possibilities.

Is it normal? Academics aren't special. People lie. I lie sometimes. I'm sure you lie sometimes. Lying is as normal in academia as it is anywhere else.

Honestly, the above answers the rest of your question too. You assume you know her situation and motivations when the fact is that you don't. You conclude that she's callous---maybe she is, maybe she isn't---again, sometimes you're going to run into a callous person, might even get (un)lucky and stumble upon a sociopath, that's just the risk you run when interacting with people. Nothing special about academia there either.

Comment: I can't get over the irony of someone named "trutheality" ("truth" + "reality") admitting to lying sometimes. Still, this is a good answer, so +1